# Android: How to invalidate multiple parts of screen

Tags: android, drawing

I need to be able to selectively invalidate multiple (about 20) rectangles on the screen for performance reasons, so tried the following:

```
Vector<Rect> myRects = new Vector<Rect>();

// ... add some Rects to myRects

for (Rect r : myRects) {
    invalidate(r);
}
```

However this seems to invalidates a union of all the `Rect`'s, forming one large rectangle which covers all of small ones I'm trying to invalidate.

How can one invalidate multiple areas on the screen, and only those areas?

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate one rect, then in the `onDraw()` check your list and and call `Invalidate()` with the next one, until the list is empty.

A better solution is to use `Drawable`s and call `InvalidateDrawable()` on those.